# Choosing between WSTI and Jax-ws

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws, java-metro-framework

My question is quite simple.

In which cases should I prefer use WSIT style (which come with Metro) rather than the standard JAX-WS?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

WSIT/Tango sits on top of JAX-WS.  You can't use one or the other, you can only use JAX-WS alone or WSIT and JAX-WS.  WSIT expands JAX-WS with extra functionality.  If you need that functionality use WSIT, if you don't, don't use WSIT.

Comment: Thanks for your response. You said "If you need that functionality". What functionality I